# What is the simplest way to make a three second timer in Android?

Tags: java, android, timer, android-activity

In the Android app I'm writing I want my activity to display my company's logo and then launch a new activity three seconds after. I have the layout done and the graphic in the right place but I don't know how to make the timer.

What is the simplest, shortest way to create the three second timer?

Thank you very much in advance for all of the responses I receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laurence Dawson's answer is fine, but (1) go straight to the Handler section, and (2) for your application you want `postDelayed` instead of `postAtTime`.

Actually there is a [nearby answer very close to what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834129/android-splash-screen-for-application-class/3839204#3839204), except that instead of calling `start`, you want to instantiate a Handler and use `postDelayed` to schedule your Runnable 3 seconds later.

Comment: You don't even need a `Handler`. `postDelayed()` is available on any subclass of `View`, such as the `ImageView` you are using for the logo.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the point, I just tested it in my application; just changed the Handler with the name of the Image before .postDelayed()

Comment: Along with CommonsWare's suggestion this was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Heres a great page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) on the Android developer docs. They create a simple timer extending the "TimerTask".

Answer (score 0):

here you go ... just tru threading .. thread will let ur activity sleep after some time and then start an intent .. and u must finish() activity when it is in pause mode :D see this

```
     Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }finally
            {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  login.class);                         
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }; t.start();
}
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```