# Making a temporary Activity .. Like a hello screen

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to make a temporary Activity that allowed me to show it , For Example it is appear only for 5 seconds so how can I make it >> Like a hello screen in the beginning in my app .

By the way I am using Android Studio

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Splash screen for "Application" class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834129/android-splash-screen-for-application-class)

Comment: That temp activity is called Splash screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splash screen displays for 2 seconds and then the main activity of the application appears. For this, we add a java class that displays the splash screen. It uses a thread towait for 2 seconds and then it uses an intent to start the next activity.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private long ms=0;
private long splashTime=2000;
private boolean splashActive = true;
private boolean paused=false;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
Thread mythread = new Thread() {
public void run() {
   try {
      while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
         if(!paused)
         ms=ms+100;
         sleep(100);
       }
   } catch(Exception e) {}
     finally {
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Splash.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     }
   }
 };
   mythread.start();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a bad way for splash. If you turn off the app during those 5s, the main screen will reappear again. The proper way is to display image from the Main screen and hide it after 5s.

Comment: @sandalone : Is it okay now ?

Comment: Press Home button before splash time elapsed and you will see what I mean